# Pure input method of JavaScript without HTML?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

In WebStorm, if a pure JavaScript file is written without HTML, the functions `prompt()` and `alert()` cannot be used for input-output. WebStorm gives the error:

> "ReferenceError:  is not defined"

What are the pure input/output methods in JavaScript without HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in [readline](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/readline.html) Node.js module could be used to prompt the user and request input. But you can also try [inquirer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer) or [prompt](https://github.com/flatiron/prompt)

To write messages to stdout, `console.log()` is the simplest native solution (available in both browser and Node.js contexts)

Answer (score 1):

**console.readline()**

This will wait for user input on console and return the input.
See this: [link](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html)

And

**console.log(output)**
can be used for showing output on the console

Comment: The answer to the question you linked returns a "Not Found We're sorry, we couldn't find what you were looking for".